# views_get_view_result additional parameters not working

Tags: 8, views

I'm trying to call views_get_view_result from a block class to load in a view. My view has two contextual filters (one for a year, one for state of node). So I'm trying to call views_get_view_result like so:

```
views_get_view_result([view_machine_name], [view_display_name], $arg1, $arg2);
```

All I get back is an empty array. The view does have default values set for the contextual filters, and when I remove the extra arguments, ex:

```
views_get_view_result([view_machine_name], [view_display_name]);
```

I get values back from the function as I would expect. What am I doing wrong with the additional parameters?

Comment: Do you have any special validation configured for the contextual filters? If you test in the views ui passing the same arguments does the preview view render your expected results?

Comment: Try with `views_embed_view` instead.

Comment: @sonfd, good call, the view was built so that the contextual filters never actually worked (parents didn't seem to to know children in relationships). I rearchitectured it, and the contextual filter worked, but views_get_view_result didn't work.

Comment: @NoSssweat, I did end up using views_embed_view, and that seems to work really well with Drupal 8's rendering system. If you wanna add that as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.